# machine in German: Maschine, Gerät, Apparat

Tags: vocabulary

I have translated machine into German. There are three translations for that: »*die Maschine*«, »*das Gerät*«, »*der Apparat*«.

I am studying the difference between them.

- Maschine

  > mechanische, aus beweglichen und unbeweglichen Elementen zusammengesetzte Vorrichtung, die Kraft überträgt oder Arbeitsgänge ganz, auch teilweise selbstständig verrichtet oder Energie aus einer Form in eine andere umwandelt
- Gerät

  > - Bezeichnung für verschiedene Arten von Apparaten, Ausrüstungsgegenständen, Werkzeugen
  > - Gesamtheit von Werkzeugen für eine bestimmte Tätigkeit
- Apparat

  > - Gerät, das bestimmte Funktionen erfüllt
  > - die zu einer bestimmten größeren Aufgabe benötigten Menschen und Hilfsmittel
  > - wissenschaftliches Hilfsmittel

(all quotes from DWDS)

I was thinking about examples, like car, train, cell phone, refrigerator, binoculars, computer mouse, computer, lawn mower, car engine, voltmeter, calculator. Can they fit into one of those categories (Maschine, Gerät, Apparat)?

What is the difference?

Comment: Similar in English: machine, device, apparatus,

Comment: Or (judging from your profile): *maquina*, *instrumento*, *aparato*

Comment: Hmm, can you fit cell phone, train and binocular into one category in English?

Comment: @Eller: I was trzýing to produce examples so that I can come to a better understanding fo those words

Comment: @Takkat: Similar, but certainly not the same. Quite some things called "machine" in English would not normally be called "Maschine" in German, but "Automat". Conversely, in German, the word "Maschine" can be used as a synonym for "airplane", which, to my knowledge, is not the case in English.

Answer (score 3):

At the university where I studied (in southern Germany) they teach the **engineering students** the following definitions:

> **Gerät**
>
> Some item that has been built to process, store or transmit any kind of information (such as texts, numbers, music, movies, …)
>
> **Apparat**
>
> Some item that has been built to perform any kind of chemical reactions
>
> **Maschine**
>
> Some item that has been build to handle forces, motion, energy or power

**It is important** to know that most people not having studied engineering sciences typically do ***NOT*** use these definitions and simply mix up these three words!

There are also examples of words in the German language where these definitions obviously do not match:

According to German grammar a *Rassierapparat* (electric shaver) is a special kind of *Apparat* (because the word ends with *-apparat)* although it processes force and energy.

A *Rechenmaschine* (calculator) is according to the grammar a special kind of *Maschine* although it processes information.

*Gartengeräte* (tools used in the garden like a spade or a pitchfork) are obviously not used to process information …

Normally Germans will not say *Maschine* to something that does not have a motor (or at least a crank, rotating parts or similar) so they will never say that garden tools are *Maschinen*.

Instead simple tools (such as garden tools) are normally called *Gerät* bei Germans.

Comment: +1 for the engineering definitions, which are odd, but common in some fields.

Comment: Also note *Maschine* is often used for *motorbike* by motorbike enthusiasts and for *jet* by news people. *Wegen des Streiks der Fluglotsen konnte keine Maschine abheben.*

Comment: And I think *Rechenmaschine* is called that way because the really old ones had a crank shaft, rotating parts (cylinder head, carburettor, spark plugs etc etc. [^.^;])

Comment: "simply mix up these three words" - but still, these words are not completely interchangeable. I for one couldn't imagine a native speaker (even though they have not studied engineering sciences!) call an electric shaver *Maschine*, although probably everyone would agree it's a *Gerät*.

Comment: For sheep, dogs, it's *Schermaschine*, but *Scherapparat* is common, too.

Comment: Der Computer, die universelle Maschine. Turingmaschine.

Comment: +1, but I must earnestly admit that, the moment I read "Gartengeräte are obviously not used to process information", my mind started to come up with counterexamples, either funny ones about how to misuse these tools for classic information-processing, or real creative ones (encode your town's name in a bed of violets of different colors), or philosophical ones related to entropy, etc.